# How to prevent displaying the selected item as list in v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How can I customize v-select to maintain the label without floating and prevent displaying selected items as a list (not removing the item from the options list with `hide-selected`)

Please find the [sample application](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) here.

Expected behavior: maintain the label Project Category all the time.

[image: expected behavior]

Current behavior: Label float to the top and list user selection
[image: Current behavior]

Comment: Your descriptions are too ambiguous.  Can you elaborate?  what does "maintain the label without floating" mean?  Also, you want the selected items to not display as a list... then what should they display as?

Comment: @yoduh apologies, I added more description. Hope this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a label, use **placeholder**, which won't float, but it will still disappear once a selection is made.  To rectify, you'll need to override the selection slot to keep displaying the same placeholder text as before.

```html
<v-select
  placeholder="Project Category"
>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
    <div v-if="index == 0">Project Category</div>
  </template>
```

The only difference now is the opacity of the placeholder text is < 1, while the selection text is 1, so you'll see that opacity change when selecting/unselecting a value.  To change the placeholder opacity to match the selection opacity you can add this style:

```css
<style scoped>
  .v-select :deep(input::placeholder) {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
</style>
```

[demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Alternatively, if you want the selection opacity to match the placeholder opacity...

```css
<style scoped>
  .v-select :deep(.v-select__selection) {
    opacity: 0.38 !important;
  }
</style>
```